# Convert from .eml to .msg in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want my users to fill out a simple form with fields like From, To, Subject, Body and Attachments. When they are done they should click on a button which lets them download a .msg file, so that they can edit it furthermore in outlook and send it.

All the converters APIs I've found for .NET are commercial (and quite pricy).

Here's my code:

```
using System.Net.Mail;


    protected void lbOpenOutlook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateEmail();
    }

    internal void CreateEmail()
    {
        // Create message
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        // subject
        message.Subject = "email subject";

        // body content
        message.Body = "email message.";

        // sender 
        message.From = new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com");

        // send this mail to
        message.To.Add("test1@gmail.com");

        // cc list
        message.CC.Add("ccuser1@gmail.com");

        // Create the SMTP Client object
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

        // store in directory 
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;

        // path of the pickup folder
        smtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Emails/");

        // deliver email
        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
```

This generates a .eml file..how could I convert it to a .msg whitout using a commercial API?

Also, I don't want to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook namespace because it works fine on the client but it's not supported on the server and my application is running under IIS.

Comment: You could distribute an outlook plugin to your users so that they can do the eml to msg conversion on the client.

Comment: Outlook also opens eml files

Comment: I am deploying a web application, I can't send to all of my users a plugin.
@DanL I have Office 2007 SP3 (NOT Express) and it doesn't.

Comment: Why can't you provide a link on your website, and tell users they have to install your plugin to open the emails in Outlook?  It's not unheard of for a "cloud" service to require users to install some client software.

Comment: @AlexanderD I have Office 2010 (NOT Express) and that does open eml as I've opened about 16 eml files today so far. If the proportion of your users who are using less than Office 2010 is small enough you can still consider it as an option. Cheers, Dan

Comment: @DanL I think they have 2010 at least, so tomorrow I will update my outlook too and see if everything works fine.
As for mbeckish, I know, but in that case let them download client software to open the mail is not an option, as for the company requirements. Everything should be done in the application

Comment: @DanL I have tried and Outlook 2010+ open .eml files correctly. The extension is just not supported on 2007. Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it properly

Comment: So 2007 sp3 does support eml files but only if you call it with /eml and it has the latest service pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** Summary of comments on the answer.

*Whilst Outlook 2007 does not support opening .eml files, Outlook 2010+ can open .eml files correctly.*

Comment: But not for drag and drop into an email folder

Comment: This answer may not be accurate anymore. https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/956693/files-that-have-the-eml-file-name-extension-do-not-open-in-outlook-200

Answer (score 1):

To convert EML to MSG you can use [Aspose.Email for .Net](https://products.aspose.com/email/net?utm_source=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652624/convert-from-eml-to-msg-in-c-sharp-net&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=convert-from-eml-to-msg-in-c-sharp-net).

This is a third-party library, which can provide you with a bunch of useful functions for working with email. 
The Email API can be used for basic email management features such as converting, message content attachment manipulation and editing, and for its advanced features such as management of the message storage files, sending & receiving emails via several protocols including POP3, IMAP & SMTP.

You can do it programmatically. For example, you can use the following code:

```
    //Initialize .EML file    
    using (MailMessage eml = new MailMessage("test@from.to", "test@to.to", "template subject", "Template body"))
   {
       string oftEmlFileName = "EmlAsMSG_out.msg";

       MsgSaveOptions options = SaveOptions.DefaultMsg;

       //Save created .MSG file  
       options.SaveAsTemplate = true;
       eml.Save(oftEmlFileName, options);
    }
```

I think this approach can be useful for you.

I am a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.